# UIAlertController ignoring the device orientation

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

I am adding a new `UIWindow` (`UIWindowLevelAlert`) with a `UIAlertController` in case `iOS 8` and above.

new `UIWindow` is rotating fine with the orientation but the `UIAlertController` goes portrait and sometimes goes off the screen.

Any suggestion??